# Disable and Enable Hyperlinks Graphics

Tags: graphics, notebooks

[image]

I have a `Graphics` element which I edit with Drawing Tools.  I have determined a technique using `NotebookWrite` to add hyperlinks to the selected shape.  My question is, how might I disable and enable the hyperlinks so that I can edit the current shape and surround shapes without invoking the links.  **Other usability ideas are welcome**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around with several techniques I decided the `CellTags` was overly complicated and didn't work consist enough, so here is simplified version.  Simply pass the Graphics element in as an argument to get alternative output.

```
disableClicks[i_] := Replace[i, {
    EventHandler[w___, {"MouseClicked" :> x___, y___}, z___] -> 
     EventHandler[w, {"MouseClicked2" :> x, y}, z],
    EventHandler[w___, "MouseClicked" :> x___, z___] -> 
     EventHandler[w, {"MouseClicked2" :> x}, z]
    }, \[Infinity]];
enableClicks[i_] := Replace[i, {
    EventHandler[w___, {"MouseClicked2" :> x___, y___}, z___] -> 
     EventHandler[w, {"MouseClicked" :> x, y}, z],
    EventHandler[w___, "MouseClicked2" :> x___, z___] -> 
     EventHandler[w, {"MouseClicked" :> x}, z]
    }, \[Infinity]];
```

Revisions: [1st](http://pastebin.com/YyBtrJhY) [2nd](http://pastebin.com/KpwWbKSL)

Comment: 1) those buttons, it is safer to put them in `Row[]` instead of multiplying them. 2) from where do you know how to work with `EventHandlerTag`?

Comment: I just ran `ToBoxes@Graphics[EventHandler[Circle[]...]]` to see the box form of the EventHandler.  Yes it could change between versions.

Comment: @Kuba I just posted a different approach entirely that no longer uses `EventHandlerTag`.

Comment: I understand that you are creating hyperlinks by your own with `EventHandler`, not with `Hyperlink`, am I right?

Comment: @Kuba I didn't think of that.  I guess you or I could further extend the code.  Early I had to take into account `EventHandler[w, {"MouseClicked" :> x, y}, z]` and `EventHandler[w, "MouseClicked" :> x, y]` which is why there are 2 replaces.  Well it is definitely a lot shorter then it used to be.

Comment: If you are implementing hyperlinks with `EventHandler` then you can `{"MouseClicked" :> (If[enabled, SystemOpen["http://mathematica.stackexchange.com"]])}` where the user is going to change `enabled` to True/False with that buttons. So now you do not have to restructurize the code.

Comment: @Kuba Certainly true.  I just don't really want to leave any gaps ;)